# WPF - Modify MahappsMetro DataGrid style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm currently working with MVVM in WPF, I installed MahappsMetro in my project. I want to change the default DataGrid style, without losing all the properties of MetroDataGrid style (Style for DataGrid from MahappsMetro).

I simply want to change some Triggers as IsMouseOver and IsSelected, I tried doing this:

I defined this Style in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <DataGrid>
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">       
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I bind this Style, where I need it

```
    Style="{DynamicResource TransparentDataGrid}"
```

But I get the exception :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

Also I tried :

I created the style in MainViewModel.xaml but I don't know how to bind this style to other views.

Answer (score 1):

to derive from existing style for the controls you need to specify the type as the key in based on attribute

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MetroDataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        ...
```

if above does not work then do prefix with correct namespace to `MetroDataGrid` eg `mapp:MetroDataGrid` where mapp points to MahappsMetro assembly

eg

```
<Application x:Class="CSharpWPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         xmlns:mapp="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls">
<Application.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="TransparentDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type mapp:MetroDataGrid}}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
              ...
</Application.Resources>
```

use the correct assembly above is just an example

Comment: {StaticResource {x:Type MetroDataGrid}} is impossible because MetroDataGrid is not supported in WPF, in App.xaml.

Comment: You need to define a namespace for the same in `<Application>` tag. eg `xmlns:mapp="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls"` and change it to `{StaticResource {x:Type mapp:MetroDataGrid}}`

Comment: I was trying, but `{StaticResource {x:Type mapp:Metro DataGrid}}` it isn't possible.
The bind would be `{StaticResource {x:Type mapp:TypeName=DataGrid}}` (Because after mapp: must be or Type or TypeName). However, with last syntax, there is a problem, "The x:type arguments are not valid".